# AIX tar error: There is not enough memory available now

Tags: tar, aix

I have an AIX P720 server running AIX 5.3. When running `tar -xvf /dev/rmt0` extracting from tape (IBM TS3100 Tape Library), I get the following error: "`There is not enough memory available now`". It also happens when I try to use `cp` to copy files. I increased paging space significantly but the problem persists.

Comment: what `errpt` says ? show last errpt logs, preferably `errpt -aj ` output.

Comment: If it is really urgent, consider opening a pmr, as people may or may not log in here. Also, check the free space in /tmp and ulimit -m.  See also http://www.blacksheepnetworks.com/security/resources/aix-mailinglist/6150.html -- are there other errors from tar?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am quite sure AIX 5.3 is not supported. Of course it may be possible that LMK has some kind of "platinum" support card ;)

Comment: I got an error initially: tar: 0511-164 There is a media read or write block size error. Now it simply gives the message "There is not enough memory available now"..

Comment: We run an old system, hence AIX 5.3. We should be upgrading in a few months

Comment: Found one other user with same error, "Known problem fixed by apar IY11431". Can you unmount/remount filesystem that you're trying to write to?

Comment: Just tried the unmount/mount option, the problem is still there. space in /tmp is 3Gb and ulimit is unlimited.

Comment: Is there space left in /var?

Comment: Filesystem    GB blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd4         100.00      2.49   98%    41385     7% /
/dev/hd2           3.00      0.15   95%    54879    59% /usr
/dev/hd9var        1.00      0.65   36%     7482     5% /var

Comment: Sorry about the formatting - var is 1Gb in size, and only 5% has been used

Comment: actually, 36% has been used

Comment: Try a larger block size.  Make sure the tape is rewound to the beginning, then do  `dd if=/dev/rmt0 bs=126b | tar xvf -`

Comment: Which fs are you trying write to?
BTW: Please add the answers to comment questions to the original question, such that your initial question provides all relevant information and is as complete as possible.

Comment: Thank you everyone for commenting, in both this comment section and the answer section.. I really appreciate it!! The battle continues

Comment: Again, I'm not convinced this has anything to do with the fact you're reading from tape. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1000459 and try and determine if your error is related to the write side.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder whether you can list the files without attempting a restore just yet. You could try doing that with `tar -tvf /dev/rmt0`

And also, is it possible that you could capture the output to a file rather than to STDOUT (your screen)?

```
tar -tvf /dev/rmt0 1>/tmp/rest.out 2>/tmp/rest.err
```

A couple of other areas to look at. Is it actually physical memory? If so, you should be seeing some hits on paging space with the lsps -a command or using a utility such as nmon (option m for memory) or topas.

One other thought: it's not something as simple as NCARGS. From memory (pardon the pun) this would give a different error, such as "the parameter list is too long." But it might be worth checking using:  `lsattr -El sys0 -a ncargs`

Some other options are to try the restore on a different LPAR, assuming that you do have another LPAR that could have that or another tape drive assigned to it.

Comment: There may be another option, assuming this is due to lack of physical memory, and that's to allocate more memory - even temporarily - using DLPAR. Of course, that assumes that there is some available memory and that it's not a standalone system, but being an entry level system like a P720 and having a dedicated tape drive, I'm guessing assigning extra memory isn't an option.

Comment: I cannot list the files with tar -tvf /dev/rmt0. it gives a different error (my problem basically alternates between these two errors:

Comment: Then you could try to rewind the tape:

tctl -f /dev/rmt0 rewind

And then list / change the block size.

Comment: "tar: 0511-164 There is a media read or write block size error." and the memory problem

Comment: I already tried rewinding the tape using tctl. It didn't seem to do the trick. I'm actually thinking of just copying the contents of the tape to disk, without extracting them and then tar the contents from disk..

Comment: Yes, you could do that.

The tctl command with the rewind worked, though, didn't it? If that failed, it might indicate that the tape is not accessible (usually because it's ejected).

What about the block size? What is the output of the lsattr command? If it's not zero, you can set the block size to zero which is a variable block size, and that should then get the block size from the backup itself (the one that was actually used for the backup).

Comment: Physical memory is ok, I have ruled that one out. Extracting from tape has worked before, - just as a side note.

Comment: So if you use the dd command to extract from the tape to the disk, you should then have a tar format file.

Good to see you've ruled out memory and file system space etc.

Comment: I set the block size to 0 a while back, in-fact, it was one of the first things to look at. Yes, rewinding the tape worked. tcopy shows me that the tape is accessible

Comment: So, you're back to the dd if=/dev/rmt0 of=/somedir/somefile
Funny how a generic error such as "out of memory" can throw you off, thinking that the LPAR is out of memory. That's IT for you!

Comment: You said this happens when you try to `cp` the files. What did you mean? Can you reproduce the same error simply copying files, without the tape drive as part of the problem? If you can eliminate the tape drive and recreate the error, this puts your problem in the JFS domain. Eliminate variables.

Comment: As this is my first time ever on Stack Exchange, cut me some slack and let me ask two dumb questions.
I'm going to approach this a little differently. Are you sure that this is a tar backup and not done by some other means such as cpio or the AIX 'backup' command? (I'm assuming you probably created the backup yourself, and so you probably are sure, but I just wanted to ask).

Also, is there some other way of getting hold of the data that is currently on the tape? I mean, is it a backup of data that is already on disk somewhere else?

Comment: Looks like I can only copy the first block, which is 320k in size.

Comment: The backup command was not used for the backup. It is a tar backup. and  oh, I don't think your questions are dumb

Comment: After copying the first block or so from tape, I "forwarded" it to what appears to be the next block, then I ran the dd command again. I get this error: dd: 0511-051 The read failed. :There is not enough memory available now.
The location I'm copying to is about 4Tb in Size, so disk space is not my problem

Comment: I still advise to take a look at errpt, some useful stuff may be logged out there. Second idea : can you do `truss tar -xvf /dev/rmt0`, maybe trace will show us some info.

Answer (score 3):

Tape devices under Unix are a bit unique in that they are record-oriented rather than being a stream of bytes. So each record written to tape must be a round multiple of some block size, usually 512 bytes, and must be done in a single `write` call. Each tape device will have lower and upper bounds for the record size. Similarly, you have to read a record in a single `read` call, supplying it with a buffer that's at least as large as the actual record size. If you try a read size that's smaller than the record size, Unix won't return a partial record; it will return the `ENOMEM` error.

Choosing the record size is up to the application. Tar has a `b` option, calling the *blocking factor*; a value of 20 means 20*512 bytes. Older operating systems limited you to 64kbyte buffers, so a popular blocking factor was 126, but newer, faster tape drives require even larger minimum record sizes. Cpio uses the `C` option to set the buffer size. To keep one's sanity, it's usually better to use `dd` to read the data from the tape drive using a given block size (with the `bs=` or `ibs=` option) and then pipe it to whatever program will unpack the data.

So try this:

```
dd if=/dev/rmt0 bs=1024k | tar xvf -
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty interesting: a wrong block size using the dd command also generates an out of memory error.

[Using 'dd' (disk dump) to verify Tivoli Storage Manager tape volume labels](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21398709)

To view or change the block size on a tape drive, you could use:

```
lsattr -El rmt0 -a block_size
```

And to change it, for example to variable,

```
chdev -l rmt0 -a block_size=0
```

But you'd want to change it back at the end of the successful restore, I expect.